# Magento not recognizing custom sql setup

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I can not get magento to execute my sql setup for the life of me. I've done this before with no problem but this application has a mind of its own cause it doesnt want to do it now. This is what I've done so far.

## app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <namespace_module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </namespace_module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

## app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {


}
```

## app/code/local/Namespace/Module/sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento Enterprise Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Catalog
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2009 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
 * @license     http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 */

$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

if (!$installer->tableExists($installer->getTable('namespace_module_table'))) {
    $installer->run("
    create table namespace_module_table (
        postal_code char(5) primary key,
        north_east_bound_lat varchar(64),
        north_east_bound_lng,
        namespace_module_address varchar(64),
        time_zone_id varchar(30)
    );
    ");
}
```

$installer->endSetup();

As a result of this, I was able to get magento to recognize my Setup.php file because it threw a error at one point, but I fixed that. But when I check the core_resources, I do not see my module setup..

I have all cacheing disabled and flush magentos cache and storage cache. and disabled and enabled my `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml`

Please keep in mind that this module is fully functional, it just doesn't have a installer which is what I am trying to do. I just gave you the bare minimum of getting this thing installed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <namespace_module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </namespace_module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

needs to be...

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Your module namespace and module name needs to match the module namespace and module name directory structure.